# Proper way to install climbing grips/holds

Tags: walls

I am planning on creating a small climbing wall for the side of my kid's Kura bed. Like this example.
[image]

Most of the guides I read are talking about creating staggered, single hole grids to attach the grips. When I look at various holds to buy on amazon, a lot of them are decidedly two-hole grips.

Such as
[image]

Some options are like these, but even they seem to have some kind of stabilizer screw hole. [image]

I'm a climbing noob so I don't really know what to expect here. Appreciate any help!

Comment: what is your question? ...... have you referred to the installation instructions for the grips?

Comment: Haven't bought any yet. I'm wanting to know if you typically use just one of the holes when you have a two hole unit like the top picture (maybe its just for variance in orientation? Almost all of the peg board solutions are single hole layouts for the grid.

Comment: use your brain .... what will happen if you only use one bolt and it is not quite tight enough because it has loosened over time

Comment: Right... so that's the question. Is it "proper" to use only one bolt as many of them only have one bolt, or do you need to use both bolts.

Comment: You need more than one fixing point - surely that much is obvious. The ones with a single bolt hole have another for a screw to stop it twisting. The others simply have two bolt holes. What else is there to figure out?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second hole is used to prevent the hold from spinning.  Typical children won't have enough weight and pull strength to cause well-made, properly-installed holds to spin, but having this hole available gives you the option for higher stability if needed.

I do not recommend buying holds that require two bolts, since you'll need to install T-nuts in the exact locations required for those holds.  This will require more work than it's worth -- it's better just to buy quality holds like [these](http://www.synrockholds.com/holds.html), [these](https://www.rockymountainclimbinggear.com/bolt-on-holds-1), or [these](https://www.metoliusclimbing.com/bolt-on_holds.html).

And if you don't expect that you'll want to change the holds or their positions often (or ever), screw-on holds that don't require T-nuts or bolts are much simpler to install; a handful of #6 drywall screws is all you need.  The suppliers in the three links I noted earlier also offer screw-on holds.